# How to check whether a string contains either nothing or just space(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to return `true` if string is containing either nothing or just space(s), else `false`.

```
var str = "";     // true
var str = "   ";  // true
var str = "  1 "; // false
var str = " s ";  // false
```

How can I do that?

I have tried using `/^\s*?$/`.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @AdamKonieska `/^\s*?$/`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^ *$/
```

- `^` - from the start
- `$` - til the end
- `*` - the string consists of *zero or more* spaces

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/dY7tU8/1)

Comment: @ndn Isn't `'\t'` empty or unicode white spaces?

Comment: @dev-null, in the comments, OP stated that he tried to use `\s` and didn't get the desired results. Having that in mind and the lack of negative feedback on his side, it is only reasonable to assume that when he says *spaces*, he **literally** means *spaces*. So to answer your question - no, a *tab* is not a *space*.

Comment: @ndn You are right ... Just for my information, may you please tell me how can I add *tab* to that regex?

Comment: @stack, you can use character set instead of a single space. A character set is defined by using `[]`. In this case `[ \t]` will match either space or tab. `\s` matches a few other kinds of whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the spaces with nothing and see what the length is.

```
var strTest = str.replace(" ","");
if(strTest.length == 0) {dowork();}
```

if the string is all spaces then the length will be 0.

Comment: `if(string.length = 0)` is always 0.

Comment: how do you figure it will always be 0? If str = " this     " - then length should be 4

Comment: Because its an assignment operator `=` and not a comparison `==`.

Comment: Javascript is my 5th/6th langauage - Im sure he got the jist.. In the future, just edit the post on an obvious typo.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
if (!str || !str.replace(/ /g, "")) {
    // str is either empty, null, undefined or has nothing in it other than spaces
}
```

This also protects you if `str` is `null` or `undefined` too.

Here's a demo using the OP's test cases:

```js
var testStrings = ["", "   ", "  1  ", " s "];

testStrings.forEach(function(str) {
  var result = false;
  if (!str || !str.replace(/ /g, "")) {
    // str is either empty, null, undefined or has nothing in it other than spaces
    result = true;
  }
  log('"' + str + '"' + " tests as " + result + "<br>");
});

function log(x) {
  var r = document.getElementById("results");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = x;
  r.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: The regex you have is going to return true if there are any spaces, you need `^` and `$` to match the OPs requirement to match strings made up of only spaces.

Comment: @AdamKonieska - I don't think you realize what this is doing.  I'm using `.replace()` so all that will be left is the non-space characters in the string and this simply tests is that string of non-space characters is empty.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're right.  I'd gotten it in my head that OP wanted `""` to be false when tested.

Comment: @AdamKonieska - You can just run the demo I added to my answer.